# what's wrong with using malloc like this?

Tags: c, malloc, segmentation-fault, assertions

I got segmentation fault for the following code, could someone help me understand why?

```
typedef struct ClientData {
        int _clientId;
        char _msg[200];
    } ClientData_t;

// in a function
char *id = malloc(50);
char *msg = malloc(sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH));
memset(id, 0, 50);
memset(msg, 0, MESSAGE_LENGTH);
strcpy(id, &(buffer[1]));
strcpy(msg, &(buffer[50]));
free(id);
printf("this message can be printed\n");
ClientData_t *newData = malloc(sizeof(ClientData_t));
// I got segmentation fault for this malloc here
```

The second time, I removed `free(id);` call from above, and kept the rest, I got the following error once the last malloc is called:

```
mainClient1: malloc.c:3074: sYSMALLOc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 * (sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long)old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
Abort
```

and finally, everything worked after I changed the first two lines in the function to:

```
char id[50];
char msg[MESSAGE_LENGTH];
```

Why is this? what could cause the assertion fail? Thank you.

Comment: How much memory do you think was allocated when the line: "char *msg = malloc(sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH));" was executed? Think about it: what does "sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH) yield as a value?

Comment: I'm not good at C, but why does second malloc has `sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH)`? if `MESSAGE_LENGTH` is `int` then second malloc allocates only `sizeof(int)` amount of memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If MESSAGE_LENGTH is an integer, then sizeof( MESSAGE_LENGTH ) is very different from MESSAGE_LENGTH.  (It is likely 4 or 8.)  You want malloc( MESSAGE_LENGTH ), not malloc( sizeof( MESSAGE_LENGTH )).

Answer (score 1):

`char *msg = malloc(sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH));`

Is probably not doing what you're thinking. I'm assuming `MESSAGE_LENGTH` is some `#define`, and if so, then it's likely you're getting the `sizeof(int)` or so, rather than allocating a block of `MESSAGE_LENGTH` bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The size of something is not its value:

```
pax$ cat qq.c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define MSGLEN 50
    int main (void) {
        printf ("sizeof(MSGLEN) = %d\n", sizeof(MSGLEN));
        printf ("       MSGLEN  = %d\n", MSGLEN);
        return 0;
    }

pax$ gcc -o qq qq.c

pax$ ./qq
sizeof(MSGLEN) = 4
       MSGLEN  = 50
```

If you want fifty bytes, use `MSG_LEN`, not its size. The code:

```
#define MESSAGE_LENGTH 50
char *msg = malloc(sizeof(MESSAGE_LENGTH));
memset(msg, 0, MESSAGE_LENGTH);
```

will allocate four bytes (assuming `MESSAGE_LENGTH` actually evaluates as an integer (on a system with four-byte integers (the standard doesn't mandate this))) but try to *fill* fifty bytes, not a good idea.